# Background Image is not visible in pdf Wkhtmltopdf with python

Tags: python, pdf, background-image, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I use Wkhtmltopdf library to create pdf from html files using python. Background image is not coming in the pdf. It's visible in html but not in pdf. I have tried giving image path from server also still not working.

wkhtmltopdf version - wkhtmltopdf 0.12.6 (with patched qt)

HTML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      font-family: "Poppins Regular", sans-serif;
    }

    html {
      min-height: 100% !important;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .page-banner-area {
      width: 100%;
      background: url("D:/Automation/images/network-tel.png") !important;
     /* background: url("http://localhost:8080/Automation/assets/images/equal.png") !important;*/

      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: cover;

    }
  </style>
  <title>TCMT</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page-banner-area">
    <div style="font-size: 50px;">Test BG Image</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Python code -

```
import pdfkit
import sys

path_wkhtmltopdf = r'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe'
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=path_wkhtmltopdf)
options = {
  "enable-local-file-access": None
}
argumentsLength = len(sys.argv) - 1
argumentList = sys.argv

print("This file is called with %i arguments" % (argumentsLength))
print(argumentList)
# remove first argument
argumentList.pop(0)
# argument list after removal of first element from list
print(argumentList)
lastItemInList = argumentList[-1]
print(lastItemInList)
del argumentList[-1]
pdfkit.from_file(
    argumentList, lastItemInList, configuration=config,options=options),
```

Command to create pdf = `python ./<python_file.py> <html_file.html> test.pdf`

Comment: could you please try giving a direct image URL from the web and check, for example, try this random image from google [image addess](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/-127wiki.jpg/1200px--127wiki.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Linux please check the ownership and permissions of the file. otherwise, you can use a direct static image web URL.

I tested the below ode code and it resolved the background image perfectly.

**HTML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 100%;
      font-family: "Poppins Regular", sans-serif;
    }

    html {
      min-height: 100% !important;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .page-banner-area {
      width: 100%;
      background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/-127wiki.jpg/1200px--127wiki.jpg") !important;
     /* background: url("http://localhost:8080/Automation/assets/images/equal.png") !important;*/

      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      height: 100%;
      background-size: cover;

    }
  </style>
  <title>TCMT</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page-banner-area">
    <div style="font-size: 50px;">Test BG Image</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**python**

```
import pdfkit
import sys

argumentsLength = len(sys.argv) - 1
argumentList = sys.argv
options = {
  "enable-local-file-access": None
}
print("This file is called with %i arguments" % (argumentsLength))
print(argumentList)
# remove first argument
argumentList.pop(0)
# argument list after removal of first element from list
print(argumentList)
lastItemInList = argumentList[-1]
print(lastItemInList)
del argumentList[-1]
pdfkit.from_file(
    argumentList, lastItemInList,options=options)
```

I refactored the code a little to run on my own machine.

**commands**

```
python ./test2.py stackoverflow.html test.pdf
```

**command line outputs**

```
This file is called with 2 arguments
['./test2.py', 'stackoverflow.html', 'test.pdf']
['stackoverflow.html', 'test.pdf']
test.pdf
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)                                               
Done
```

**screenshot of generated pdf**
[image: test.pdf]

**Also, I had already set up pdfkit using [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-convert-html-pdf/) guide.**

Comment: Have tried with css which you provided but still no luck. Could you please give html file & the command you run to create pdf  ? so that i can follow exact steps as yours & see the differences between yours & mine code

Comment: Sure. I am adding the full code to this answer.